# All links in python flask form behave like submit

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, httprequest

I am trying to get all links inside a flask form working properly:

If I press a normal link `<a href="/"></a>`, my form act like if i have pressed my submit button. For better understanding, here an explanation, what i exactly want:
If I call `station_form.html` via flask, I get my input form with pre filled inputs. These input can be changed. If I press `Back` or `Upload`, it calls `mod_station`. This shouldn't happen.
[GIF-Example of my problem - it should let me upload a file. The file upload windows opens in the background, but flask don't stay on this page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QreYh.gif)

**station_form.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('mod_station', old_station=form.station_name.data) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Modify {{ form.station_name.data }}</legend>
            <div class="row responsive-label label_center spacer_20">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 row_title">{{ form.station_name.label }}</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md">{{ form.station_name }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row responsive-label label_center spacer_20">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 tooltip row_title" aria-label="Only a *.png file.">{{ form.station_cover.label }}</div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md">
                    <div class="upload_wrapper">
                        <button class="secondary button_fix">{{ form.station_cover }}Upload cover</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row responsive-label label_center">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="/"><button class="secondary large">Back</button></a></div>
                <div class="col-sm-0 col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    {{ form.submit(class="tertiary large add_station_submit", value="Modify station") }}
                </div>
            </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddStationForm(FlaskForm):
    station_name = StringField('Station name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    station_cover = FileField('Cover', validators=[FileAllowed(['png'], '*.png only!')])

    submit = SubmitField('Add station')
```

**main.py**

```
@app.route("/station_form")
def station_form(station=None):
    form_station = AddStationForm()
    if station is not None:
        form_station.station_name.data = station[1]
    countries = helpers.load_country_choices()
    success = False

    return render_template('station_form.html', form=form_station, countries=countries)

@app.route('/mod_station/<string:old_station>', methods=['POST'])
def mod_station(old_station):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        old_name = old_station
        if 'station_cover' in request.files:
            file = request.files['station_cover']
            if file.filename != '' and file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(TEMP_PATH, filename))
                success, message, station = station_model.modify_station(request.form, os.path.join(TEMP_PATH, filename), old_name)
                return render_template('report.html', success=success, message=message, station=station)
        filename = request.form['station_name'] + ".png"
        old_file = os.path.join(THUMBS_PATH, old_name + ".png")
        new_file = os.path.join(THUMBS_PATH, filename)
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
        success, message, station = station_model.modify_station(request.form, filename, old_name)
        return render_template('report.html', success=success, message=message, station=station)
```

I tried to reduce the code already. Hope you can tell me, where my mistake is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` element submits form by default. To prevent it from form submission, you must set its type explicitly to `type="button"`.

Your `a` elements contain buttons without type so add type for them e.g.

```
<button class="secondary button_fix" type="button">{{ form.station_cover }}Upload cover</button>
```

You can read more about button element behaviour in its [w3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)